# Obtain global linear regression estimate from subsamples

Tags: regression, least-squares, computational-statistics

I want to estimate $\widehat\beta$ in a simple linear regression with scikit.

$$y = X \beta + \varepsilon$$

The problem is that the dimension of the complete $X$ is too large to fit into memory. Is there a way to split up the problem theoretically. Say, split up the sample into $n$ subamples randomly:

$$y^1, \ldots, y^n, X^1, \ldots, X^n$$

For each subsample get $\widehat\beta^1, \ldots, \widehat\beta^n$ and then combine these with some weighting function $\theta$ to get: $\theta(\widehat\beta^1, \ldots, \widehat\beta^n) = \widehat\beta$

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: I gave an answer without random splitting, which does not seem to add value in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an indirect answer to the question that does not proceed by weighting coefficient estimates, but gradually computing the ingredients into the "global" estimate. I believe that `biglm` in `R` proceeds similarly.

Note that

$$
\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'y
$$
where $X'X=\sum_{i=1}^Nx_ix_i'$ with $x_i'$ the $i$th row of the regressor matrix. Likewise, $X'y=\sum_ix_iy_i$. Now suppose you divide $N$ into $n$ manageable blocks of size $m$,  $N=n\cdot m$.

You may now load each block into memory consecutively. Then, with $x_{j,k}'$ the $k$th observation of block $j$,
$$X'X=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^mx_{j,k}x_{j,k}'$$
Each of the $\sum_{k=1}^mx_{j,k}x_{j,k}'$ yield an "unproblematic" matrix of size $k\times k$ ($k$ being the number of regressors, which I assume is not huge, but that the number of observations $N$ is).

A possible code snippet in R (sorry, I do not know python) might look like this - just for illustration, no claim to efficiency/elegance:

```
N <- 1000 # the "large" sample size
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rnorm(N)
m <- 100
n <- N/m

x.sq <- x.y <- rep(NA,n)

for (j in 1:n){
  x.sq[j] <- sum(x[((j-1)*m+1):(j*m)]^2)
  x.y[j] <- sum(x[((j-1)*m+1):(j*m)]*y[((j-1)*m+1):(j*m)])
}
> (beta.hat <- sum(x.y)/sum(x.sq)) # recombining the samples and computing OLS (without intercept for simplicity)
[1] -0.04175772

> coef(lm(y~x-1)) # here, of course, everything fits into memory and we can check equality
          x 
-0.04175772
```